# How to get a copy of a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

I am very new to `database` and `programming`.

I have created database on **one PC**. Now I need to get a copy of same DB and have it on **my PC**(including the tables and its data).

I have SQL Server 2005.

When I try to export the database it will ask for another machine.

Please provide me guidance or beginners level example link

Comment: try ro backup your db :) here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191304(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: How large is the database?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - It is not a large database. has 5-6 table with nearly 40-50 data records

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this, but I'm a huge proponent of [`BACKUP`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28SQL.90%29.aspx) and [`RESTORE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Create a folder called `c:\temp\` and give `EVERYONE` full control. Open a query window in SSMS.

```
BACKUP DATABASE database_name
  TO DISK = 'C:\temp\database_name.BAK' WITH INIT;
```

Also run the following to determine the logical filenames:

```
USE database_name;
GO
EXEC sp_helpfile;
```

Now copy the file to the other machine (in a folder also called `c:\temp`). And in a query window on that instance:

```
RESTORE DATABASE database_name
  FROM DISK = 'C:\temp\database_name.BAK'
  WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY,
  MOVE 'data file name' TO '...path...\database.mdf',
  MOVE 'log file name'  TO '...path...\database.ldf';
```

You'll need to replace some variables there but hopefully that provides the gist.

Comment: what should I mention as `data file name` and `log file name`?

Comment: Like I said, you need to run sp_helfile, you'll see the logical names there - data file is the one with the .mdf name, and log file is the one with the .ldf name,

Comment: Your answer perfectly work fine with small DB. Now I need to Backup large DB. This not working for that. Any alternative I can do??

Answer (score 0):

You can backup and restore the database.

Another method is to go to SQL Server Management studio and script out all objects in the database.

On the advanced tab, you can choose to have it script out the data in tables too.

To get to the wizard, right click on the database, choose "Generate Scripts", and follow the instructions in the wizard.

Then, you can save it out as a file.  Or, you can just paste it into a SSMS window connected to the other database and run it.

You would *not* do this for a database that has any significant amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

this will help u...

go to your database,select database which you want to use on other pc,right click on it go to task->select detach,then it will show database name then click OK.
After this its .log and .mdf file goes to c:/program files/Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA .here you will find your database name 2 files ,from this you copy it and past it where you want it.you can get database on another pc .

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to Backup and Restore like Aaron already suggested but here is another thing you can try.

1. Stop SQL Server services.  (Go to SQL Server Configuration manager -> SQL Server Services -> Right click SQL Server service and click stop)
2. Go to SQL Server data folder (Right click on the database -> Properties -> Files)
3. Copy MDF and LDF files to another computer
4. Start the SQL Server services again from the SQL Server Configuration Manager

On target machine open SQL Server Management Studio, right click on the Databases folder and click Attach and select MDF and LDF files you copied.